# Почему все, что было объявлено с помощью var, не отображается в инструментах разработчика?

Tags: javascript, отладка, google-chrome-devtools

Если открыть "Инструменты разработчика", то не будет видно как создается этот объект, какой внутренний объект к нему был еще добавлен... - ничего. Почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var o = {
    name: 'Eva'
};
var o2 = {};
o.a = o2; // o ссылается на o2
o2.a = o; // o2 ссылается на o
```

Но стоит только изменить оператор `var` на `let`, как все сразу становится видно. Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let o = {
    name: 'Eva'
};
let o2 = {};
o.a = o2; // o ссылается на o2
o2.a = o; // o2 ссылается на o
```

Такое происходит и с переменными. Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти `var`/глобальные переменные находятся в другом месте -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переменная, объявленная с помощью `var` считается глобальной, потому что имеет функциональную область видимости (видна отовсюду, кроме функции)? Правильно?

Comment: "видна отовсюду, кроме функции" - ??

Comment: @Eva "Переменная, объявленная с помощью `var` (или без `var`) не внутри функции, считается глобальной." - достаточно.

Comment: плохая формулировка) я имею в виду, что переменная, которая была объявлена с помощью оператора `var` может быть видна только в пределах той функции, в которой она была объявлена - это единственной ограничение. В остальных случаях она видна "отовсюду"

Comment: @Eva Хорошо. :)